# Gridster stop: get new canvas layout instead of 1 widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridster

I am trying to  implement a gridster save option into my application.

Gridster resize stop is working for 1 widget.. my goal is to get the whole layout data back instead of 1 single widget.

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    tagname: "",
    setupGridster: function() {
        var self = this;

        Ember.$(".gridster ul").gridster({
            widget_base_dimensions: [359, 232],
            widget_margins: [5, 5],
            helper: 'clone',
            //gridster api ?
            serialize_params: function(w, wgd) {
                return self.serializeWidget(wgd);
            },
            resize: {
                enabled: true,
                max_size: [3, 3],
                min_size: [1, 1],
                stop: function (e, ui, $widget) {
                    self.sendAction("saveLayout", {
                        data: self.serializeWidget($widget)
                    });
                }
            },
            draggable: {
                stop: function (e, ui, $widget) {
                    self.sendAction("saveLayout", {
                        data: self.serializeWidget($widget)
                    });
                }
            }
        }).data('gridster');
    }.on("didInsertElement")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To serialize the whole grid instead of just one widget, use the .serialize() method instead of .serializeWidget(). 
Also, make sure you use :

```
serialize_params: function ($w, wgd) {
                        return {
                            componentId: $w.prop('id'),
                            col: wgd.col,
                            row: wgd.row,
                            size_x: wgd.size_x,
                            size_y: wgd.size_y
                        };
                    },
```

in your gridster configuration object.

Comment: Thanks for your responce. I've tried this functions allready before, but haven't got a clue how to implement this. The console callback I've get from the code in de first post is from the line: self.sendAction("saveLayout", {
                        data: self.serializeWidget($widget)
Could you help me a bit or take a look to my code?

Comment: sure, just put your working code on jsfiddle, save it, and send me the link, i'll try and edit it there

Comment: Actually, nevermind, here is the fiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/h9f63/60/

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Actually here's the fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/h9f63/60/

Hope this helps you.

```
 serialize_params: function(w, wgd) {
            return {
                        col: wgd.col,
                        row: wgd.row,
                        size_x: wgd.size_x,
                        size_y: wgd.size_y
                    };
        },
        resize: {
            enabled: true,
            max_size: [3, 3],
            min_size: [1, 1],
            stop: function (e, ui, $widget) {
                var gridData = gridster.serialize();
                //send data from this variable to your function
                console.log(gridData)
            }
        },
        draggable: {
            stop: function (e, ui, $widget) {
                var gridData = gridster.serialize();
                //send data from this variable to your function
                 console.log(gridData)
            }
        }
```